# How to add Class-Path to the manifest file with maven

Tags: java, maven, manifest

When using the maven-jar-plugin 

I would like to add entry to the Manifest.mf 

So it will contain:

Class-Path: .

When i add this entry to the Pom:

```
<Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
```

It will create Class-Path with all dependency

Like:

Class-Path: . jar1name.jar jar2name.jar etc

Instead of just 

Class-Path: .

Is there a way to avoid maven from adding all jar names to the Class-Path?

Thanks

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Built-By>Me</Built-By>
            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path> 
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: generally jars you don't want in classpath at runtime are marked as `provided`, does it solve your case?

Comment: I don't want any jar on the Class-Path in the manifest, provided or not, I just want to output "."

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This did the trick

Omitting the addClasspath and adding manifestEntries

Now, log4j.properties can reside outside the jar - and still be found...

```
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                </manifest>
```

This is working:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Built-By>Me</Built-By>
             <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Output:

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
 Created-By: Apache Maven
 Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_45
 Built-By: Me
 Class-Path: .
```